# How to display circles in a non-grid form

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to achieve the layout in the image below using CSS. As you can notice that it's not in a grid format. I tried `shape-outside: circle();` but it doesn't work as I expected. How can I get to do it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Circles</title>

  <style>
  img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    shape-outside: circle();
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: An awful lot of absolute positioning. You'll need JS to manage that. I'm sure there are plugins that will do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you recommend a plugin please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still use grid, but just use the `align-self` and `justify-self` properties, with the `start`, `center`, and `end` values to stagger them out how you want them:

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  shape-outside: circle();
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  padding: 5px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

html, body{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

body{
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}

.grid{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 500px;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(1){
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: center;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(3){
  align-self: end;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(4){
  justify-self: end;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(5){
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(7){
  justify-self: end;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(8){
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.grid > img:nth-child(9){
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/70" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/90" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/40" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/85" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/45" />
</div>
```

Comment: What if the content is dynamic and I don't want to use JS? Do you think masonry could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my version to generate CSS that so you do not have to use the Javascript version. Run the javascript fiddle and then open up inspector and copy and paste the console output and put that in your CSS file. The first fiddle generates the CSS and the second fiddle demonstrates that the CSS works. It is dynamic to work perfectly as you add more photos because it works from the center outward.

Generate CSS in console: https://jsfiddle.net/jp7q6xa1/5/

Demo showing CSS only positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/rda5c46j/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Circles</title>

  <style>
  img {
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    shape-outside: circle();
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  .container {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px
  }
  </style>
  <script>

  function overlaps(x1, y1, radius1, x2, y2, radius2) {
    var xDistance = x1 - x2;
    var yDistance = y1 - y2;

    var sumOfRadii = radius1 + radius2;
    var sumOfRadiiSquared = sumOfRadii * sumOfRadii;
    var distanceSquared = xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance;

    return distanceSquared  < sumOfRadiiSquared;
}

  function adjustLayout(containerID) {
    var container = document.getElementById(containerID);

    var images = container.querySelectorAll("img");

    var minGapBetweenCircle = 10;

    var plottedCircleInfo = [];

    var radius, plotX, plotY;

    var centerX = container.offsetWidth / 2;
    var centerY = container.offsetHeight / 2;

    var plotXYRadius = 1;
    var plotXYRadians = 0;

    var radius = 50;
    var maxRadius = 40;
         var minRadius = 50;

        var CSS = ".container {position:relative} .container img {position:absolute;border-radius:50%};";

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
         var failed = true;
         while (failed) {
             radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRadius - minRadius + 1)) + minRadius;


             var plotXYRadiusOffset = plotXYRadius + Math.random() * 10;

             plotX = centerX + Math.cos(plotXYRadians) * plotXYRadiusOffset;
                 plotY = centerY + Math.sin(plotXYRadians) * plotXYRadiusOffset;

             failed = false;

             for (var c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                 var circle = plottedCircleInfo[c];
                 if (overlaps(circle.m_xPos, circle.m_yPos, circle.m_radius, plotX, plotY, radius + minGapBetweenCircle)) {
                      failed = true;
                      break;
                 }
             }


             plotXYRadians += 0.01;
             if (plotXYRadians > Math.PI * 2) {
                    plotXYRadius += 1;
                plotXYRadians -= Math.PI * 2;

             }
        }

        plotXYRadians += Math.PI;

        var smaller = Math.random() + 0.5;
        if (minRadius > 20) {
                    minRadius-= smaller;
                  maxRadius-= smaller * 0.66;
        }
        //console.log(plotX, plotY, radius);

        CSS += ".container img:nth-child("+ (i + 1) +") { left:" + (plotX - radius) + "px; top:"+ (plotY - radius) + "px;width:" + (radius * 2) + "px;height:" + (radius * 2) + "px;}";




        images[i].style.left = (plotX - radius) + "px";
        images[i].style.top  = (plotY - radius) + "px";
        images[i].style.width = (radius * 2) + "px";
        images[i].style.height = (radius * 2) + "px";

        plottedCircleInfo.push({m_xPos : plotX, m_yPos : plotY, m_radius : radius});
    }

    console.log(CSS);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="spreadCircles" class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
  </div>

  <script>adjustLayout("spreadCircles");</script>
</body>
</html>
```